# Transformation tool from geth genesis.json to parity format

Tags: private-blockchain, parity, genesis

Is there any tool transferring geth genesis file to the format accepted by parity?

I guess it could be done manually but it leave too much space for human factor.

Comment: Here it is: https://github.com/keorn/parity-spec

Comment: Is there an equivalent tool that converts the other way, that you know of? @maxtaldykin